# Design Patterns for Image Transformation

Tags: php

I would like to write an image conversion process in laravel.

The process I want to do is different for jpg, png and gif.
What design pattern can I adapt?

The code is here.

```
        $image = $request->file('image');
        if($image->getMimeType() == "image/jpeg"){
            $enc = Image::make($image)->resize(1200, null, function($constraint){
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                $constraint->upsize();
            })->encode("jpg");
            $file_name = time().random_int(1,1000000).".jpg";
            $quority = 80;
        }else if($image->getMimeType() == "image/png"){
            $enc = Image::make($image)->resize(1200, null, function($constraint){
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                $constraint->upsize();
            })->encode("jpg");
            $file_name = time().random_int(1,1000000).".jpg";
            $quority = 80;
        }else if($image->getMimeType() == "image/gif"){
            $enc = Image::make($image);
            $file_name = time().random_int(1,1000000).".gif";
            $quority = 100;
        }

        $enc->save(storage_path("app/public/".$file_name),$quority);
```

jpg converted to jpg with quality 88.
png to jpg with quality 88.
Save gif as gif.

Maybe webp and svg will be added.

Comment: You're looking for a creational pattern, [factory](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/php/example) would work.

Answer (score 0):

Couple general tips:

`getMimeType()` once like so:

```
$mimeType = $image->getMimeType()
```

then use [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement

```
switch ($mimeType) {
    case "image/gif":
    // do your stuff here
    break;
}
```

Use some kind of code formatting tool, use more spaces so your code is more "readable". Finally try not to repeat code to much, fe:

```
 $file_name = time().random_int(1,1000000).".jpg";
 $file_name = time().random_int(1,1000000).".gif";
```

You can wrap it into function or at least separate this part `$file_name = time().random_int(1,1000000)` and then only add extension